# decryption equivalent of openssl rsautl -decrypt -oaep -inkey xx.pem -in cyphertext.enc -out plaintex.txt

Tags: .net, encryption, openssl, rsa

I can decrypt a base64 encoded encrypted string using an RSA private key (-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ----MIIG4wIBAAKCAYEA1HZEO4eUxTjpA7eRzvs3Ew7tVQQ8i1zmr+ZpSooF+fVqm9VE
ZVnE0WslHccLfkpoh8q+Zr3lpGqTtiEzlX9BmRN2y7VrrJV7HMGQCB2eO4dpUVCZ
vcI/5OChdYsswlFS....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
with openssl using

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -oaep -inkey xx.pem -in cyphertext.enc -out plaintex.txt
```

I am trying to do the same in .net.
I have tried the following using bouncycastle:

```
string cyphertext = File.ReadAllText(@"data_encoded.txt");
                var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cyphertext); // string to decrypt, base64 encoded

            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"private_key.pem")) // file containing RSA PKCS1 private key
                keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
                decryptEngine.Init(true, keyPair.Private);
                var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length)); //input data too large

var engine = new RsaEngine();
                engine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);  
                var decrted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(engine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length)); //produced corrupted data : [6��oe쩪\u0017^p/\u0003�`M-�?6\u0019w1�\u0012�d"
```

Comment: Please post complete **test** data, i.e. complete key and complete ciphertext, and also a complete C# code (including key and chiphertext import) and describe the problem.

Comment: At least one bug is a different padding: OAEP in the OpenSSL statement, PKCS#1 v1.5 in the .NET code fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in the code:

- The OpenSSL statement loads the ciphertext as binary data. Therefore, in the C# code the ciphertext must not be loaded as string and then Base64 decoded, it just needs be loaded as binary data:

  ```cs
  byte[] bytesToDecrypt = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToCiphertextFile);
  ```

  However, if the ciphertext in the file is really Base64 encoded, then this was achieved with another OpenSSL statement or done afterwards. In this case the change would not be necessary.
- As already mentioned in the comment, the padding is wrong. The OpenSSL statement applies OAEP with SHA1 for both digests, so the C# code must also use OAEP instead of `Pkcs1Encoding()`:

  ```cs
  var decryptEngine = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine(), new Sha1Digest(), new Sha1Digest(), null);
  ```
- For decryption the first parameter in `decryptEngine.Init()` must be `false` and not `true`:

  ```cs
  decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);
  ```
- All lines from and including `var engine = new RsaEngine();` make no sense for decryption and must be removed.

With these changes, a ciphertext generated with the posted OpenSSL statement can be successfully decrypted.

Comment: Thanks, @Topaco. Can I buy you coffee?